# Loading Muicss styles in React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

Im trying to setup an app using Muicss for styling my components in a React js app.

Below is the code of a very simple example but when I go to my browser the button has no style in it, and I don't know if I'm missing something, I used Material Design before and I had no issues.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'muicss/lib/react/button';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button variant="raised" color="danger">button</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to get if I'm missing something, I installed the library using NPM and inside my node_modules folder I can see all the files from the Muicss library.

In the console there's no error or something weird, the weird thing is that the components have no styles...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use MUI React you must include the MUI CSS file in your HTML payload. It can be compiled into your app's CSS or added from the CDN:

```
<link href="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.30/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

(source: [MUICSS documentation](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/react/introduction))

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just have one more question...  I'm not using html files, all ara js, even my "home" page is a js file so how can I add the css? In the case of the cdn what happens if my network doesn't allow me to go to an external source, I need to download or load the css locally right?

Comment:  You can't view a web page in a browser without an HTML file, even if it just contains a single div that you render your React layout in.

Comment: And yes, simply download the file and serve it from your own server

Comment: I add a screenshot of my project structure, my home file is the home.jsx file

Comment: and I also add the code on the home.jsx file, so when I go to my browser I can see the content..

Comment: So where are those other CSS files included from? Put the mud.min.css in the same dir as custom.css, normalize.css, etc. and include it the same way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159777/discussion-between-patrick-hund-and-kennechu).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and as it doesn't mention it for future reference for passers-by it can be imported into scss using `@import url("//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.1/css/mui.min.css");`

Answer (score 0):

*Muicss version*: 0.10.2

Using the solution of [Muicss Docs](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/react/introduction) is ok but not well, because when a developer update `muicss` and do not update the given link, everything maybe ruins, now with the below solution it became very very better.

I have the same issue and fix it by adding `sass-loader` to Webpack and also I have `CSS Modules` so in the root of styles of my project I write just like below:

```
/* root file of styles.scss */

:global {
  @import 'node_modules/muicss/lib/sass/mui';
}
```

After using this solution, even with hashed class name by using `CSS Modules` I gave the global names of `muicss` and every component works well.